# Are end of string regex's optimized in .NET?

Tags: .net, regex

*Aside: Ok, I know I shouldn't be picking apart HTML like this with a regex, but its the simplest for what I need.*

I have this regex:

```
Regex BodyEndTagRegex = new Regex("</body>(.*)$", RegexOptions.Compiled |
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Notice how I'm looking for the end of the string with `$`.

Are .NET's regular expressions optimized so that it doesn't have to scan the entire string? If not, how can I optimize it to start at the end?

Comment: Seems a strange question - any reason to suspect that they _wouldn't_ be?

Comment: Well, I'm going to be doing this on a very long string and I just want to know if there's a better way to optimize it.

Comment: So really this is just in aid of being more concise than calls to `LastIndexOf` and `Substring` ?

Comment: Would `LastIndexOf` with insensitive be more performant?

Comment: Well `LastIndexOf` definitely works backwards from the end (just checked decompile) and I don't know of any clever techniques like Boyer Moore for **last** index of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can control it itself by specifying [Right-to-Left Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#RightToLeft) option, but regex engine does not *optimize* it itself automatically until you do it yourself by specifying an option:

I believe key point is:

> **By default, the regular expression engine searches from left to right.**
>
> You can reverse the search direction by using the
> RegexOptions.RightToLeft option. The search automatically begins at
> the last character position of the string. For pattern-matching
> methods that include a starting position parameter, such as
> Regex.Match(String, Int32), the starting position is the index of the
> rightmost character position at which the search is to begin.

**Important:**

> The RegexOptions.RightToLeft option changes the search direction only;
> it does not interpret the regular expression pattern from right to
> left

Comment: I just did a quick test using the OP's regex expression on a long string, using 10,000 iterations. 1,950ms without RegexOptions.RightToLeft, just 64ms with it.

Comment: ...and using `LastIndexOf` combined with `Substring` is faster still - just 15ms. But unless you've a good reason, I'd stick with the regex for readability & maintainability :)