# Benchmarking .Net regex options - or what does RightToLeft do?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, benchmarking

I've created a demo application to test the performance of some regexes. My third test uses the option [RightToLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx).

It seems it speeds up the process a lot! Why? What does it do?

Here is my test app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string IsRequestForDirectoryWithoutTrailingSlashRegex = @"^(?#Path:)(.*/)?(?#LastPart:)(?<!\.asmx|\.aspx/)([^./?#]+?)(?#QueryString:)(\?.*?)(?#Anchor:)?(#.*)?$";

        private static string[] Tests = new string[] {
            "http://localhost/manager/page.aspx",
            "http://localhost/manager/",
            "http://localhost/manager",
            "http://localhost/manager/?param=value",
            "http://localhost/manager/dir?param=value"
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test1();
            Test2();
            Test3();
            Test4();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Test1()
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(IsRequestForDirectoryWithoutTrailingSlashRegex);
            DoWork("1", regex);
        }

        public static void Test2()
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(IsRequestForDirectoryWithoutTrailingSlashRegex, RegexOptions.Compiled);
            DoWork("2", regex);
        }

        public static void Test3()
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(IsRequestForDirectoryWithoutTrailingSlashRegex, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
            DoWork("3", regex);
        }

        public static void Test4()
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(IsRequestForDirectoryWithoutTrailingSlashRegex, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.RightToLeft | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            DoWork("4", regex);
        }
        static void DoWork(string name, Regex regex)
        {
            Stopwatch sp = new Stopwatch();
            sp.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                foreach (string s in Tests)
                {
                    regex.IsMatch(s);
                }
            }

            foreach (string s in Tests)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(":" + s + ":" + regex.IsMatch(s).ToString());
            }

            sp.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Test " + name + ": " + sp.ElapsedTicks);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this: [Are end of string regex's optimized in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528852/are-end-of-string-regexs-optimized-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`RegexOptions.RightToLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#RightToLeft) can be useful when you are trying to match a pattern that you expect to find at the end of the input string, because as its documentation say: The search goes from <del>right to left</del> left to right starting at the final character in the input string, the regex itself though is still applied from left to right.

<del>Your regex seems to be looking for a trailing slash for directory paths, so it seems like this is a situation that fits the description.</del>

Although your expression is looking for a trailing slash, the presence of those two anchors *(`^` and `$`)* makes my reasoning wrong, because the regex can match only in one possible way no matter where it starts.

I am going to keep looking for the actual reason behind this, but for now I will leave my answer as is.

<del>On the other hand, the `.*/` part of the expression right after the `(?#Path:)` part at the start of your expression consumes the entire input string then it goes back recursively each time to find the last `/`, so when starting the search further ahead there might not be a lot of backtracking.</del>

Comment: Nice, nice, nice. Explains a lot!

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker Sorry, I have changed my answer, please check edit. I am up voting you question because this is really weird.

Comment: I'm looking forward to your findings. It is really faster (50% in my tests).

Comment: Any luck in your investigation?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker Well No. I was going to suggest that you raise a bounty for this as it really irritates me.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker I have been off stackoverflow for quite some time now. Job taking all time. You could raise a bounty if you are so interested and someone who is more knowledgeable might give you a convincing answer.